# get post ids for two different values from same table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables:

```
tabel1
id name address
1  ss    aaaa
2  ee    wwww

tabel2
id tid key value
1  1   rr   ggg
2  1   ww   ttt
3  2   rr   ggg
4  2   ww   ttt
```

I want to fetch values of tabel1 where "key" is (rr AND ww) and value is (ggg AND ttt).
I am using this:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM tabel1 t1 JOIN tabel2 t2 ON  t1.id = t2.tid WHERE (t2.key = 'rr' AND t2.value ='ggg') OR (t2.key='ww' AND t2.value = 'ttt')
```

But Iam getting only this:
tabel1

```
  id name address
   1  ss    aaaa
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.* FROM tabel1 t1 JOIN tabel2 t2 ON  t1.id = t2.tid WHERE (t2.key = 'rr' AND t2.value ='ggg') OR (t2.key='ww' AND t2.value = 'ttt')
```